# How would I deserialize this particular property using Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json.net

Good day all.

The question is: how would I deserialize "GenericCounts" property using Json.NET. If it was something like 'myproperty':1 there would be any problem but I do not know what to do with numbers in that case? Any suggestions?

```
@"{  
   'status':0,
   'result':{  
      'UploadId':'740e358c-090e-4891-acbf-3eaf6c7b3ccd',
      'Status':0,
      'ItemCount':0,
      'GenericCounts':{  
         '8':1
      }
   }
}";
```

Comment: Please post a code which you used for DeSerialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `8` isn't fixed, and that it can contain arbitrary values:

```
public Dictionary<string,int> GenericCounts {get;set;}
```

or maybe (worth a try, but might not work)

```
public Dictionary<int,int> GenericCounts {get;set;}
```